# Is it okay to mix legacy SSE encoded instructions and VEX encoded ones in the same code path?

Tags: assembly, x86, sse, avx

Along with the introduction of AVX, Intel introduced the VEX encoding scheme into the Intel 64 and IA-32 architecture. This encoding scheme is used mostly with AVX instructions. I was wondering if it's okay to intermix VEX-encoded instructions and the now called "legacy SSE" instructions.

The main reason for me asking this question is code size. Consider these two instructions :

```
shufps xmm0, xmm0, 0
vshufps xmm0, xmm0, xmm0, 0
```

I commonly use the first one to "broadcast" a scalar value to all the places in an XMM register. Now, the instruction set says that the only difference between these two (in this case) is that the VEX-encoded one clears the higher (>=128) bits of the YMM register. Supposing that I don't need that, what's the advantage of using the VEX-encoded version in this case? The first instruction takes 4 bytes (`0FC6C000`), the second - 5 (`C5F8C6C000`).

Thanks for all the answers in advance.

Comment: Does any YMM register have an upper half that is used?

Comment: No, it doesn't. They can be zeroed or randomized or whatever, I don't care.

Comment: Then it's fine. On current implementations, if the upper halves have been reset (VZEROUPPER) there is no penalty for using legacy SSE instructions.

Comment: @harold This should be an answer. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah I guess I'll add some info and turn it into an answer..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On current implementations, if (at least) the upper halves have been reset (VZEROUPPER or VZEROALL) there is no penalty for using legacy SSE instructions.

As detailed on page 128 in [Agner Fog: optimizing subroutines in assembly](http://www.agner.org/optimize/optimizing_assembly.pdf), using legacy SSE instructions while (some) upper halves are in use carries a performance penalty. This penalty is incurred once when entering the state where YMM registers are split in the middle, and once again when leaving that state.

Mixing VEX-encoded 128-bit instructions and legacy SSE instructions is not a problem.

Comment: See also [Why is this SSE code 6 times slower without VZEROUPPER on Skylake?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41303780) for the different penalty for having dirty uppers while using legacy SSE instructions, compared to Haswell and Ice Lake mechanism where it's only on transitions.

Comment: According to Intel, in Golden Cove CPUs (Alder Lake-P, Raptor Lake-P, Sapphire Rapids) this penalty have been inscreased compared to previous CPUs.

"The Golden Cove CPU microarchitecture has increased the cost of mixing Legacy SSE and VEX without clearing the state of upper registers for power efficiency reasons. When possible, use VEX-encoded instructions for all the SIMD instructions when possible".
[Section 3.11.5](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/content-details/671488/intel-64-and-ia-32-architectures-optimization-reference-manual.html) of Intel Software optimization manual.

Answer (score -1):

It's not safe. According to [Intel's software developer manual](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/a4/60/325383-sdm-vol-2abcd.pdf), `VEX.128` version zeros the upper half of the YMM register, legacy SSE version doesn't. Worst thing: some assemblers (like gas) may convert `SHUFPS` into `VSHUFPS` while creating object file (when `-mavx` flag is applied). I found exact same problem working with an assembly file.

Comment: `gcc -mavx -c foo.s` still assembles the instructions as written.  There is a GAS option `-msse2avx` ([`as(1)` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/as.1.html), *not* a `gcc` option unless you use `-Wa,-msse2avx`).  GCC doesn't pass it on my system with `-mavx`, and it's not on by default.  I'd be surprised if any distro ever had gcc pass it when you didn't explicitly use it, but I guess it's plausible.