# ASM x86_64 AVX: xmm and ymm registers differences

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-64, avx

What are the differences between `xmm` and `ymm` registers?
I thought that `xmm` is for SSE, and `ymm` is for AVX, but I wrote some code:

```
vmovups     ymm1, [r9]      
vcvtss2si   rcx, ymm1
```

and it gives me:

```
error: invalid combination of opcode and operands
```

It's about the line:

```
vcvtss2si   rcx, ymm1
```

So I wrote:

```
vcvtss2si   rcx, xmm1
```

and it works as intended. The first value of `ymm1` vector, converted to integer, is now in `rcx`.

What is it all about? `ymm1` and `xmm1` are the same registers?

Comment: The main difference between `xmm1` and `ymm1` (as well as for the other indexes) is that the former is 128 bits long while the latter 256.

Comment: So `xmm1' and `ymm1` share the same memory?
If I want to use instruction that use only first 128 bits it doesn't matter if I use `xmm` or `ymm`? Or maybe every instructions that use only first 128 bits require using `xmm`?

Comment: Ok, so I'm coping 256 bits of data from memory:
`vmovups     ymm1, [r9] `
Then I convert first element of `xmm1` (not the `ymm1`) and save it in the `rcx`:
`vcvtss2si   rcx, xmm1`
How is it possible that in `rcx` is the first value of `ymm1`? Shouldn't it be a 'random' number from `xmm1`?
If  `xmm1` and `ymm1` are independent registers, why are the first element of `ymm1` and `xmm1` the same?

Comment: I found a pretty simple diagram on wikipedia:
[link](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f5/AVX_registers.svg/330px-AVX_registers.svg.png).
If I understand it correctly YMM and XMM are overlapping and XMM is contained in YMM. Right?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I now understand that I was wrong. You are right, the low 128 bits are common to both registers. Please disregard my previous comment.

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia: you can (and should) delete your incorrect comments.  `xmm0` is the low half of `ymm0`, exactly like `eax` is the low half of `rax`.  (And writing `xmm0` zeros the upper lane of `ymm0`)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`xmm0` is the low half of `ymm0`, exactly like `eax` is the low half of `rax`.

Writing to `xmm0` (with a VEX-coded instruction like `vaddps xmm`, not legacy SSE `addps xmm`) zeros the upper lane of `ymm0`, [just like writing to `eax` zeros the upper half of `rax` to avoid false dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-x64-instructions-zero-the-upper-part-of-a-32-bit-register).  Lack of zeroing the upper bytes for legacy SSE instructions is why there's a [penalty for mixing AVX and legacy SSE instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41303780/why-is-this-sse-code-6-times-slower-without-vzeroupper-on-skylake).

Most AVX instructions are available with either 128-bit or 256-bit size.  e.g. `vaddps xmm0, xmm1, xmm2` or `vaddps ymm0, ymm1, ymm2`.  (The 256-bit versions of most integer instructions are only available in AVX2, with AVX only providing the 128-bit version.  There are a couple exceptions, like `vptest ymm, ymm` in AVX1.  And `vmovdqu` if you count that as an "integer" instruction).

Scalar instructions like `vmovd`, `vcvtss2si`, and `vcvtsi2ss` are only available with XMM registers.  Reading a YMM register is not logically different from reading an XMM register, but *writing* the low element (and leaving the other elements unmodified, like the poorly-designed `vcvtsi2ss` does) would be different for XMM vs. YMM, because the YMM version would leave the upper lane not zeroed.

---

**But scalar with ymm doesn't exist in the machine-code encoding, even for instructions where it would be really useful like `vpinsrd` / `vpextrd` (insert / extract a scalar).**

Note that even though reading an XMM register and taking only the low scalar element is logically the same as YMM, for the actual implementation it would *not* be the same.  Reading a YMM register implies an AVX-256 instruction, which would have to transition the CPU out of the "saved upper" state (for an Intel CPU with SSE/AVX transitions / states).

In any case, `vcvtss2si rax, ymm0` is not encodeable, and the assembler doesn't magically assemble it as `vcvtss2si rax, xmm0`.  If you're writing in asm, you're supposed to know exactly what you're doing. (Although some assemblers will optimize `mov rax, 1` to `mov eax, 1` for you, so letting you get away with writing `ymm` as a source register would work.  But letting you write `ymm` as a destination register for `vcvtsi2ss` would change the meaning, so for consistency it's better that it doesn't do either).

Answer (score 10):

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions#Advanced_Vector_Extensions), in AVX:

`YMM` registers are **256 bits** long.

`XMM` registers are **128 bits** long and represent **the lower 128 bits** of the `YMM` registers.

The `YMM` and `XMM` registers are overlapping and `XMM` are contained in `YMM`.

Diagram from [wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:AVX_registers.svg):

[image: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:AVX_registers.svg]