# What is the bit representation of a single float number inside ymm0 register (not memory)?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, floating-point, cpu-registers

A float in memory takes 4 bytes, but a single `ymm0` has room for 8 floats, so how do all bits in the `ymm0` look after a float value gets loaded into it? When performing float arithmetic, I am still loading only 1 number per register.

Under what circumstances is the remaining space in the register used?

I know how to use a union of float and unsigned int to read bits from memory as `hex`. I imagine register as a small memory with a single address, how are the bits of a float organized inside a register?

Comment: If you only load a single float, only the low 32 bit are used.  The remaining bits remain unchanged.  It's similar to how changing al doesn't affect the remaining bits of eax.

Comment: @fuz: `vmovss xmm0, [mem]` zero-extends into the full XMM/YMM/ZMM register.  Merging would be a performance disaster (false dependencies, etc.). Fortunately Intel avoided that mistake for loads with SSE1, even though they took the short-sighted approach for PIII for stuff like `cvtsi2ss xmm0, eax` and `sqrtss xmm0, xmm1` which do have false dependencies.  Maybe you were thinking of `vmovss xmm0, xmm1, xmm2` which *does* merge xmm2 into xmm1, and writes the result to xmm0. 
 https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movss.  (Use `vmovaps` to copy scalar floats normally.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for correcting me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bit-pattern in the low 32 bits of a vector reg matches memory: [IEEE binary32 single-precision floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format).  You can use SIMD-integer stuff to manipulate it, like `psrld xmm0, 23` to shift the exponent field to the bottom of the dword.  (And stuff like this is used in practice to implement exp/log for scalar or SIMD).

Background: Originally there was SSE1 (aka just SSE) with Pentium III, which only had 128-bit / 16-byte XMM registers and only single-precision `float` (not `double` or integer SIMD).  [AVX1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions) widened XMM regs to 256-bit YMM, and added different (VEX) encoding for 128-bit instructions that zero-extends to clear the part outside the low 128-bit XMM part.  (`vaddps xmm,xmm,xmm` or `ss` instead of `addps xmm,xmm` or `ss`).  AVX512 widened to 512-bit ZMM (and added masking as a first-class operation that can be part of any other instruction).

The upper bytes of a YMM register are "don't care" as far as doing scalar FP math is concerned.  **But every asm instruction has well-defined semantics for what it does to the full register: loads zero-extend, ALU operations merge into the old value** (including `movss xmm,xmm`) merge a new low element into the existing destination.

For one-source operations including `sqrtss xmm, xmm`, `sqrtss xmm, [mem]`, or `cvtsi2ss xmm0, eax`, the destination would have been write-only so this creates a false dependency.

Intel's short-sighted design for SSE1 creates output dependencies that compilers have to work around, especially in int->FP conversion.  (Pentium III split 128-bit operations into 64-bit halves, so zero-extending would have cost it an extra uop.)

**A `vmovss xmm0, [mem]` load from memory zero-extends into the full XMM/YMM/ZMM register**.  As per the Operation section [in the Intel manual](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movss):

```
  VMOVSS (VEX.128.F3.0F 10 /r when the source operand is memory and the destination is an XMM register) ¶
DEST[31:0] ←SRC[31:0]
DEST[MAXVL-1:32] ←0
```

The legacy SSE encoding of the instruction (`movss xmm0, [mem]`) zero-extends into the XMM element but leave the upper elements of the YMM/ZMM unmodified.  (Introducing the possibility of performance problems if the CPU doesn't know they're zero so it can avoid actually merging:  [Why is this SSE code 6 times slower without VZEROUPPER on Skylake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41303780/why-is-this-sse-code-6-times-slower-without-vzeroupper-on-skylake))

Fortunately Intel avoided their false-dependency merge-into-destination mistake for loads with SSE1 (and SSE2), even though they did that for stuff like `cvtsi2ss xmm0, eax` and `sqrtss xmm0, xmm1`.

`vmovss xmm0, xmm1, xmm2` *does* merge xmm2 into xmm1, and writes the result to xmm0.  (Zero-extended into ymm/zmm0 of course). https://felixcloutier.com/x86/movss.  Use vmovaps to copy scalar floats normally, by copying the whole XMM register.

> Under what circumstances is the remaining space in the register used?

**Most obviously when you want to do 8 FP operations at once with `...ps` packed-single SIMD instructions instead of `...ss` scalar single**.

SIMD is why vector registers are wide in the first place.

You can also have *leftover* garbage in the high elements of a vector register, e.g. after some shuffle/add to get a horizontal sum down to 1 scalar `float` it's normal to have non-zero high elements.

Even across function call boundaries, the ABI does *not* guarantee the upper elements are zero; your caller might have calculated a scalar in the bottom of a vector register and be passing it to your `float` function.

If you want to strictly follow FP exception semantics, you need to make sure you don't do calculations that raise exceptions if there's a NaN or other garbage in the high elements.  And for performance, operating on those unknown bit-patterns could create a subnormal result.  (Or they could be subnormal inputs).  So you could end up taking a > 100 cycle microcode assist to sort that out if you carelessly use `addps` instead of `addss`.