# Broadcasting DWORD to YMM

Tags: assembly, simd, avx, micro-optimization

I am just wondering if the below code:

```
mov eax, r9d    ; eax = j
mul n           ; eax = n * j
shl eax, 2      ; eax = 4 * n * j
                ; now I want to 'broadcast' this to YMM, like so:
                ; ymm = { eax, eax, eax, eax, eax, eax, eax, eax }
```

```
  ; This requires AVX512, not just AVX2
  ; vpbroadcastd ymm7, eax
```

```
  movd xmm7, eax             ; therefore I must do this workaround?
  vpbroadcastd ymm7, xmm7    ; and finally, the result
```

Can this somehow be simplified or optimized?

Comment: That’s [what gcc does](https://godbolt.org/z/Md7cq9),  so probably hard to beat.

Comment: The alternative is to store this on the stack and use the memory-sourced `vpbroadcastd`. At least on Intel CPUs this can be beneficial if you are bottlenecked on port5 µ-ops.

Comment: The only optimization I see is replacing `mul n` with `imul r9d, n` since you're not using the EDX high half of the multiply result anyway.  (And of course if `n` is an immediate constant, `imul eax, r9d, n*4`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `vmovd` + `vpbroadcastd` is the normal way if you don't have AVX512, for both Intel and AMD CPUs.

---

I see 2 optimizations:

**Replace `mul n` with `imul r9d, n`** since you're not using the EDX high half of the multiply result anyway.  2-operand `imul r32, r/m32` is a single uop on all modern CPUs; `mul r/m32` takes multiple.  https://uops.info/ https://agner.org/optimize/.  (And of course if `n` is an immediate constant, `imul eax, r9d, n*4`).

**Use a VEX prefix** on `movd xmm7, eax`.  i.e. **`vmovd xmm7, eax`.**  If any YMM registers have dirty upper halves when legacy-SSE `movd` writes xmm7, it will trigger an AVX-SSE transition penalty on Haswell and Ice Lake.  ([Why is this SSE code 6 times slower without VZEROUPPER on Skylake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41303780/why-is-this-sse-code-6-times-slower-without-vzeroupper-on-skylake) has the details for both HSW/ICL and the different strategy SKL uses.)

---

Without AVX512, yes, it takes a uop (like a `movd` instruction) to transfer data from GP-integer domain to SIMD domain, and that uop can't also broadcast.  You then need another uop to do a shuffle.

As @chtz points out, **if port 5 pressure in the back end on Intel CPUs is the major bottleneck** for a loop including this (instead of total front-end uops or latency), you could `mov` store (e.g. to the stack) and `vpbroadcastd` reload.

Both `vmovd xmm, r32` and `vpbroadcastd` can only run on port 5 on Intel CPUs.  But a store is micro-fused p237 + p4, and a broadcast-load (of 32-bit or wider elements) is handled purely in a load port, not ALU uop needed, so the total cost is still 2 front-end uops on Intel CPUs, with a cost of `p237+p4  +  p23`.  Instead of `2p5`.  **Store-forwarding latency of ~5 or 6 cycles actually similar to 1 to 3-cycle `vmovd` + 3-cycle `vpbroadcastd`** so maybe this is worth considering for 32-bit and 64-bit broadcasts from registers, if there isn't much pressure on the load/store ports.

(Including maybe SSE3 `movddup` broadcast-loads into XMM registers, although in-lane shuffles are only 1 cycle latency so movd + xmm shuffle is only about 4 cycle latency on Haswell and later.)

It's easy to measure the latency of a `movd xmm, r` / `movd r, xmm` round trip, but hard to figure out which instruction has which latency.  They might just be 1 cycle ALU plus a 1-cycle bypass delay on Skylake.  Haswell apparently has 1-cycle `movd` in each direction.  https://uops.info/ just measures a not-very-tight upper bound on latency by putting it in a loop with instructions to create a loop-carried dependency, and assuming others have 1-cycle latency.  https://agner.org/optimize/ makes a guess on how to split up latency for a pair of instructions. Perhaps one could do better by including store-forwarding for one direction and an ALU transfer for the other, but store-forwarding latency on Sandybridge-family is notoriously variable, faster if you don't try to reload right away.  (e.g. useless stores can speed up the critical path through a store-forwarding bottleneck.  [Adding a redundant assignment speeds up code when compiled without optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49189685/adding-a-redundant-assignment-speeds-up-code-when-compiled-without-optimization)).  And store-forwarding between an integer store and `vmovd xmm` reload can't be assumed to have the same latency as an integer reload.

Skylake's `movd` xmm<->eax round trip is a total of 4 cycle latency, up from 2 in Sandybridge / Haswell.  That could be 2 and 2 with bypass delays, or 1 and 3 without telling us which direction is slower.

Zen's is 6 cycles, so maybe 3 cycles each way.

---

**AVX512F `vpbroadcastd ymm, r32` is single-uop (port 5)**, so it's very good if you have AVX512.