# How does MSVC avoid mixing SSE and AVX?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sse, avx

Despite an infamous penalty for mixing SSE and AVX encoding (see [Why is this SSE code 6 times slower without VZEROUPPER on Skylake?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41303780/2945027)), there may be a need to mix 128-bit and 256-bit operations.

The penalty can be avoided by always AVX encoding, even for 128-but operation, or adding `vzeroupper` before any SSE encoding.

For compiler-generated code, if AVX is enabled, a compiler would assume that AVX is available, and will use AVX encoding. For every function that can be called externally, a compiler would insert `vzeroupper` in the end.

MSVC however allows generation of AVX code without AVX enabled via the direct use of intrinsics (unlike some other compilers which would require an AVX-enabling option to use AVX intrinsics).

How would it avoid mixing SSE and AVX if both intrinsics are used in a single function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler would use AVX encoding after the first AVX intrinsic.
For example, the following function:

```cpp
void test1(__m256i* dest, char x, char y)
{
        __m256i a = _mm256_broadcastw_epi16(_mm_cvtsi32_si128(x)); // movd then vpbroadcastw
        __m256i b = _mm256_broadcastw_epi16(_mm_cvtsi32_si128(y)); // vmovd then vpbroadcastw
        _mm256_store_si256(dest, _mm256_andnot_si256(a, b));
}
```

would have the first `_mm_cvtsi32_si128` encoded as `movd`, and the second as `vmovd`. And it will insert `vzeroupper` in the end.

It will use AVX encoding from the beginning if a parameter is taken via AVX register (this happens using `__vectorcall` calling convention). The same way, if `__m256i` type is returned, `vzeroupper` will not be inserted in the end.

This does not apply to unoptimized compilation. With `/Od` or no `/O...` option, it will just use the minimum level encoding for any of the instructions. It will also not insert `vzeroupper` in the end for unoptimized compilation.

[Godbolt's compiler explorer demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7h7va1x6E).

---

### Unfortunately, this does not always work

In [this issue](https://github.com/google/highway/issues/2029) it was discussed that in some situation MSVC still emits non-VEX-encoded SSE in AVX code. This:

```cpp
#include <intrin.h>

static __m128i __vectorcall f1(__m128i a, __m128i b)
{
    return  _mm_add_epi32(a, b);
}

__m256i __vectorcall f2(__m128i a, __m128i b)
{
    // Non-VEX+VEX
    return  _mm256_cvtepi16_epi32(f1(a, b));
}

__m256i __vectorcall WholeFunction(__m128i a, __m128i b) {
    __m256i c = _mm256_xor_si256(_mm256_castsi128_si256(a), _mm256_castsi128_si256(b));
    return _mm256_xor_si256(f2(a, b), c);
}
```

Makes the compiler mix `paddd` and `vmovups`.

[Godbolt's compiler explorer demo](https://godbolt.org/z/n5dY7z1G9).

I've created [Developer Community issue 10618264](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Mixed-AVX-and-SSE-code-emits-mixed-VEX-e/10618264).